# How is father of physics appointed?

Tags: terminology, history

I've tried Google, but couldn't figured out exactly whether its Newton, Einstein or Galileo.
What is the criteria for appointment of father for a particular subject?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you think that there is a formal committee that votes and names who is appointed a "father" for various particular subjects?

Comment: The physics community does not have an official "father" (oh my what a patriarchal term!).

Comment: No one is the father of physics because it was invented with the invention of a wheel. The person who invented a wheel wouldn't be the father of physics.

Comment: Can you describe " Father" ?
If newton be a female, then what you would have called it?

Comment: @علیآفاق Are u questioning yourself in the comments?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terms like "Father of Physics" (or "Father of Modern Chemistry", or "Mother of Computer Science") aren't official titles, they're just subjective opinions. No one appoints them.

Calling Einstein the Father of Physics is like giving your dad a "Best Dad in the World" mug--it's a nice gesture, but no one ever did a survey of every dad in the world to conclusively prove that he is indeed the greatest father in recorded history.

Newton, Einstein and Galileo could *all* be considered "Fathers of Physics," because they contributed immensely to human knowledge.

Comment: Can I be father of physics if I name my child 'Physics'. :D

Comment: @manshu - Hmmmmm..... After they go to school and get teased about their name your chance of receiving a "Best Dad in the World" mug might be pretty slim!

Comment: @JonCuster Who wants to be the "Best Dad in the World" if i can be the father of physics. I will have other kids to call me the best dad. :p

Comment: There is the old story of the chemist who named his daughters Methyl, Ethyl and Propyl... Not sure how that worked out for him.

Comment: Is there's any one whom we say " Mother of subject" ?
A female can also be like Einstein. Does gender really changes terms in science?

Comment: You're right I guess. Marie Curie would be "Mother" of Radioactivity and not "Father" of Radioactivity. So yes, gender really changes terms in science even though calling someone "mother" and "father" of a subject have really nothing to do with the actual subject which makes this question pretty much useless.

Comment: This answer notwithstanding, it must be noted that James Brown is objectively the Godfather of Soul.

Comment: dad of physics does not seem to be a bad choice. :-)

Comment: Archimedes should probably be considered to be the father of physics.